# if A, B, C are subsets of a Universal set U. if A∩B⊆A⊕B⊕C then A∩B⊆C

Tags: elementary-set-theory

i tried to proof this sentence.
i don't understand where to put the Parenthesis? and if need this?
i will be happy for hint\begin of the answer

Comment: Symmetric difference corresponds to the XOR operation, and hence it is associative.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

**Hint**

Let $x \in A \cap B$, then $x \in A$ and $x \in B$ and from the given condition, $x \in A \oplus B \oplus C$. Since $x$ is in both $A$ and $B$, what can be said about the membership of $x$ in $A \oplus B$???

Comment: x∈(A⊕B) ̅
and than de morgan law?

Comment: @MatanOrlan You have the right idea. From what we said above, $x \not\in A \oplus B$ and yet we have $x \in (A \oplus B )\oplus C$. Now simply apply the definition for $\oplus$ to conclude that $x \in C$.